# change a href when click div jquery

Tags: jquery, click

My problem is that I can't change a `href` in my `div` after click.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="menu"><a href="#second">Dalej</a></div>
```

```
var i=1;
var x1 = '<a href="#second">Next</a>';
var x2 = '<a href="#three">Next</a>';
$(".menu").click(function(){
  if (i==1) {$(this).html(x);i++;}
  if (i==2) {$(this).html(x2);i++;}  
});
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: please share your html code with us

Comment: `$(this).html(x);i++;` I think you have an error here. variable `x` is not there.

Comment: You have a typo. `x` is not defined. Assume you mean `x1`?

Comment: That's a typo. Please close as such. Change `if (i==1) {$(this).html(x);i++;}` to `if (i==1) {$(this).html(x1);i++;}`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have x1 variable. Rewriting code... Sry. Doesn't work again

Comment: @KarolJankiewicz Doesn't it work still?

Comment: `if (i==1) {$(this).html(x);i++;}
    if (i==2) {$(this).html(x2);i++;} ` What is the sense of this? This will just ends to `if (i==2) {$(this).html(x2);i++;}` since you increment the `i` at first condition.

Comment: <div class="menu"><a href="#second">Next</a></div>

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Do you want to show next and previous ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var i=1;
$(".menu").click(function(){
  if (i==1) {$(this).children("a").attr("href", "#second").html("next");i++;}
  if (i==2) {$(this).children("a").attr("href", "#three").html("next");i++;}  
});
```

Maybe this is better way to achieve what you want? Although I don't fully understand what you want...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu"><a href="#second">Next</a></div> 

   var i=1;
    var x1 = '<a href="#second">Next</a>';
    var x2 = '<a href="#three">Next</a>';
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        if (i==1) {$(this).html(x);i++;}
        if (i==2) {$(this).html(x2);i++;}  
      });

change this

if (i==1) {$(this).html(x);i++;} 

to 

if (i==1) {$(this).html(x1);i++;}

https://jsfiddle.net/ check your codes here
```

Comment: That's not the issue.

Comment: its working its change the href to three see it for yourself

Comment: The answer was not the same how you wrote it before.